# Google Maps getLocation

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to create app that showing user location when map created for the first time. In `onMapReady` method I've set `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` 
In the manifest, I've added the following permission to allow GPS and Network location tracking `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. But when I'm trying to get `map.getMyLocation()` it returns `null`. Please, help me to fix this.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getMyLocation(); // returns always null
    }
```

UPD: Location button doing nothing when onClick (((

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa, done

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa, if You need more code just say, I don't do anything different to the google maps sample.

Comment: You need to get the current location first and set it to map in order to show to the user, where is that part ?

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa, I dont know how to set my current location. I've been thinking that this method should return it (((

Comment: Use GPSTracker class to get the current lat and long. Then add a marker to the map using the. You will find lots of tutorials regarding that.

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa, I'm using this totourial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ but always equals null

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa, and networkEnabled is always false

Answer (score 0):

The [actual documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()) says that `getMyLocation()` "*Returns the currently displayed user location, **or null** if there is no location data available.*"

So, apparently you have no location data available and the code works as documented.

GPS might not work indoors and it might anyway take a while to get a GPS fix. Inserting a SIM card to the phone will help getting the GPS fix (via "assisted GPS") and it would also enable getting a rough location based on the cellular network even if GPS is not found.